# (GCC) How can I AND two boolean with the == operator?

Tags: c, boolean-logic

So one day I was trying to do boolean algebra with minimal characters in C, and I can only go so far as I'm stuck in this phase...

```
//You need main(){} in every C program. 8 chars: 'm', 'a', 'i', 'n', '(', ')', '{', '}'
//You also need to assign things. 1 more char
//no stdio since we don't need I/O
n; //assigns to 0 aka FALSE
i = n==n; //assigns to 1 aka TRUE;
a = i; m = n; //example booleans
a = (a == n); //assigns a to it's own logical NOT value
a = (a == m); //assigns a to the XNOR value of a and m
a = (a == m) == n //assigns a to the XOR value of a and m
```

So how would I do something like a = a AND b or a = a OR b using assiggnment, XOR, NOT and XNOR?

Comment: You can combine operators with, for example, `a = m && !n`.

Comment: What about the `^` XOR operator ?

Comment: @GabrielT that would of course solve everything but the question is about doing it using only 'm', 'a', 'i', 'n', '(', ')', '{', '}' and '='

Comment: Sorry, I get it now, very nice, I will try it myself you got me interested

Comment: Your first expression `n;` doesn't do anything, and `n` is undefined in the posted code. It *may* be zero, or it may be anything else.

Comment: I don't see a way to get AND or OR from true, false, NOT, XOR, XNOR, and equality comparison.

Comment: You may have to add i to be able to make the int keyword and declare n outside of the main function so it's initialized to 0

Comment: a AND b or  a OR b using assiggnment, XOR, NOT and XNOR" --> Not logically possible.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Practically an answer. Just add a proof explanation. ;-)

Comment: @TomKarzes  in GCC global variables are assigned to an int with the value of 0 if they don't get assigned to anything else. It throws a warning though

Comment: @MinhĐứcHoàng Yes, that's true (for C, not just gcc).  It still doesn't explain the `n;` expression.  Or was that just meant to be an example of how to get a false value?  It wasn't clear from the post (or that `n` was global).  In any case, `n;` doesn't do anything, and at best will be optimized away.

Comment: @GabrielT You can try and combine things like this with parentheses: a = (x == (y == z)).